# How can I pass an extra variable to a tidymodels fit function?

Tags: r, tidymodels, lasso-regression

I am writing a tidymodels engine to fit the joint LASSO described [here](https://academic.oup.com/biostatistics/article/21/2/219/5091415) and implemented in [the fuser package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuser/). This is a LASSO model for regression that allows partial sharing of information between groups, in this case tissues in a biomedical RNAseq experiment.

An important difference between this and the regular LASSO is that while it also takes as arguments a matrix of predictors `X` and a vector of outcomes `Y`, it *also* takes a vector of group indicators, which in my case would be the tissue that each observation belongs to.

I would like to pass in a column name or `role` to the `groups` argument of the fit function, so that in a resampling/cross-validation loop, the groups argument corresponds to the grouping of the subset of data used in the resampling loop.

I can't find any information in [the parsnip docs](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/develop/models/) describing how to specify extra variables/selections/etc in the fit function. If I try to add it to the engine definition as I've done below, then when I try to use the engine in a normal tidymodels pipeline, I get an error that `groups` is missing (expected, given I haven't specified how to pass it to the fitting function).

```r
library("tidymodels")
## the content of src/tidymodels-utils.R is at the bottom of this question
## beginning with set_new_model
source(here("src/tidymodels-utils.R"))


nfeats <- 100
nsamples <- 120
ngroups <- 2
group <- sample(letters[1:ngroups], nsamples, replace=TRUE)
predictors <- matrix(rnorm(nfeats*nsamples), nrow = nsamples, ncol = nfeats,
    dimnames = list(paste("Sample", 1:nsamples), paste("Feature", 1:nfeats))
)
outcome <- rnorm(nsamples)

## tidymodels wants a dataframe input
input <- data.frame(
    predictors,
    group = group,
    outcome = nsamples
)

norm_recipe <- recipe(input) %>%
    update_role(matches("Feature"), new_role = "predictor") %>%
    update_role(outcome, new_role = "outcome") %>%
    update_role(group, new_role = "group") %>%
    ## some steps to center/scale/select predictors and outcome omitted here
    prep()

glmnet_model <- joint_lasso(penalty = tune(), fusion = tune(),
        groups = matches("group")) %>% 
    set_engine("fusedLassoProximal")

workflow <- workflow() %>%
    add_recipe(norm_recipe) %>%
    add_model(glmnet_model)

folds <- vfold_cv(input, v = nfolds, repeats = nrepeats)

glmn_set <- parameters(
    penalty(),
    fusion()
)
glmn_grid <- grid_regular(glmn_set, levels = 3)
ctrl <- control_grid(save_pred = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)

results <- workflow %>%
    tune_grid(
        resamples = folds,
        metrics = metric_set(rmse),
        grid = glmn_grid,
        control = ctrl
    )
# Error in `mutate()`:
# ℹ In argument: `object = purrr::map(call_info, eval_call_info)`.
# Caused by error in `purrr::map()`:
# ℹ In index: 1.
# Caused by error in `.f()`:
# ! Error when calling fusedLassoProximal(): Error in unique(groups) : argument "groups" is missing, with no default
# Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Any ideas where this will fit? There's a lot of boilerplate but my journeys through the various `?` pages hasn't shown anything obvious.
Worth noting that the prediction method will also need this group information about the test data in each resample, because the return value of `fuser::fusedProximalLasso` is simply a matrix of coefficients, one column for each unique value of `group`.

The whole set of function calls to define the engine (and the `fusion()` penalty param) is as follows:

```r
set_new_model("joint_lasso")
set_model_mode(model = "joint_lasso", mode = "regression")
set_model_engine(
    "joint_lasso", 
    mode = "regression", 
    eng = "fusedLassoProximal"
)
set_dependency("joint_lasso",
    eng = "fusedLassoProximal", pkg = "fuser"
)


set_model_arg(
    model = "joint_lasso",
    eng = "fusedLassoProximal",
    parsnip = "penalty",
    original = "lambda",
    func = list(pkg = "fuser", fun = "fusedLassoProximal"),
    has_submodel = FALSE
)

set_model_arg(
    model = "joint_lasso",
    eng = "fusedLassoProximal",
    parsnip = "groups",
    original = "groups",
    func = list(pkg = "fuser", fun = "fusedLassoProximal"),
    has_submodel = FALSE
)

joint_lasso <- function(
        mode = "regression", 
        penalty = NULL,
        fusion = NULL,
        groups = NULL) {

    if (mode  != "regression") {
        rlang::abort("`mode` should be 'regression'")
    }
    
    args <- list(
        groups = rlang::enquo(groups),
        penalty = rlang::enquo(penalty),
        fusion = rlang::enquo(fusion)
    )
    
    # Save some empty slots for future parts of the specification
    new_model_spec(
        "joint_lasso",
        args = args,
        eng_args = NULL,
        mode = mode,
        method = NULL,
        engine = NULL
    )
}

set_fit(
    model = "joint_lasso",
    eng = "fusedLassoProximal",
    mode = "regression",
    value = list(
        interface = "matrix",
        protect = c("X", "Y", "groups"),
        func = c(pkg = "fuser", fun = "fusedLassoProximal"),
        defaults = list()
    )
)

set_encoding(
    model = "joint_lasso",
    eng = "fusedLassoProximal",
    mode = "regression",
    options = list(
        predictor_indicators = "traditional",
        compute_intercept = TRUE,
        remove_intercept = TRUE,
        allow_sparse_x = FALSE
    )
)

predict_joint_lasso <- function(object, new_data=NULL) {
    ## some code here to use the new data
}

pred_info <- list(
    pre = NULL,
    post = NULL,
    func = c(fun = "predict_joint_lasso"),
    args =
        list(
            object = quote(object$fit),
            new_data = quote(new_data)
        )
)

set_pred(
    model = "joint_lasso",
    eng = "fusedLassoProximal",
    mode = "regression",
    type = "numeric",
    value = pred_info
)

show_model_info("joint_lasso")

fusion <- function(range=c(0, 2), trans = NULL) {
    new_quant_param(
        type = "double",
        range = range,
        inclusive = c(TRUE, TRUE),
        trans = trans,
        label = c(fusion = "Fusion parameter"),
        finalize = NULL
    )
}
```

Comment: Have you checked out how parsnip uses [case weights](https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/reference/case_weights.html)? It sounds like there is some overlap here with your use case.

Comment: Noting that `func` in `set_model_arg` should be something like `list(pkg="dials", fun = "penalty")` rather than what I've used here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should write a wrapper function to provide a different interface for that function. Your point about resampling is spot-on and you need a way to point fuser's functions to specific columns in the data.

We had similar issues with the [gee](https://github.com/tidymodels/multilevelmod/blob/main/R/gee.R#L1-L49) function, which also had an argument for a length `n` vector of groups.
In that case, we used the little documented "specials" feature of base R formulas.

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/topepo/6b9c8e6240f69c719c137fc41614e1a2) that has an implementation if you want to use it. Basically, you would require a formula to be used that has a `groups()` function in it. The variable in that function defines the groups. It's all there.

One other thing (addressed in the gist): the `G` argument is data-dependent. If a user uses a recipe or some tool that might reduce features, then the dimensions might be off. There is a function that will take the `G` argument as an expression and then evaluate it with the number of columns that are actually in the data. There are other (and probably better) approaches, but I thought I'd point that out.

Feel free to put in a parsnip R if there is more that we can help with.

Comment: I think G is groupwise, not featurewise? Other than that very helpful, I was quite lost on what direction to go even within the `fit_*` functions.

Comment: `recipes:::inline_check` is run on the recipe formula method and that disallows any functions other than `c("~", "+", "-")`, so how would I actually use this in a recipe?